# Ajax GET Asp.net MVC value not display

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

I try use GET Ajax to retrieve the data by calling their ID from two table that have join. It already hold the data in controller but it can't display the data. It give "error" and HTTP500: SERVER ERROR in console. How should I fix it?

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult GetData(int? id)
        {

           List<Quest> quizz = (from material in db.MaterialLearnings
                                 join quiz in db.Quests on material.id equals quiz.IdMaterial
                                 where material.id == id
                                 select quiz).ToList<Quest>();
                         
            return Json(quizz, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

**AJAX GET**

```
function beginQuiz(id) {
    console.log(id)
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "Home/GetData/"+ id,
        dataType: "json",
        data: {},
        success: function (data) {
            start.style.display = "none";
            getQuestion(data);
            quiz.style.display = "block";
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
   
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with either `"Home/GetData/?id="+ id` or `data: {id: id},`

Comment: I try it, but still doesn't work

Comment: When you tried `data: {id: id}` did you remove `id` from ` url: "Home/GetData/"+ id,` ?

Comment: Do you have a `[Route]` configured to match `id` (might be the default one)?   Or use `?id=` as suggested above

Comment: If you're getting a 500 error then the Action is probably being called but failing - debug/step through the C# action or add error handling to the Action (basic: wrap in a try-catch)

Comment: I already do it, but can't work too. It seems like because of return Json it can't work

Comment: as per your code,  I can see your URL should be "/Home/GetData" like this, without "/" it takes "Home/Home/GetData" , so try with this **url: "/Home/GetData/"+ id**